# I need to add a class only to the image element only if the src value is empty or file extension is wrong

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
                const images = document.querySelectorAll('.header');
                images.forEach(findImageExtension);
                function findImageExtension(images) {
                    var src = images.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
                    var fileExtension = src.split('.').pop();
                    console.log(fileExtension)
                    if (!src || fileExtension != 'jpg' || fileExtension != 'png' || fileExtension != 'svg' || fileExtension != 'jpeg' || fileExtension != 'gif') {
                        $('.image').addClass("invalidImage")
                    }
                }
            })
```

```css
.image.invalidImage {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
<img loading="lazy" data-object-fit="" class="image" src="/sites/default/files/2021-02/DOVE%C2%AE%20PROMISES%C2%AE%20Silky%20Smooth%20Dark%20Chocolate.jpg" alt="DOVE® PROMISES® Silky Smooth Dark Chocolate">
        
<h2 class="heading">
      DOVE® PROMISES® Silky Smooth Dark Chocolate
  </h2>
  </div>
  
<div class="header">
<img loading="lazy" data-object-fit="" class="image" src="/sites/default/files/2021-02/DOVE%C2%AE%20PROMISES%C2%AE%20Silky%20Smooth%20Dark%20Chocolate.jpg" alt="DOVE® PROMISES® Silky Smooth Dark Chocolate">
        
<h2 class="heading">
      DOVE® PROMISES® Silky Smooth Dark Chocolate
  </h2>
  </div>
```

If I try to remove any one src value or try to change the extension of any one file, the class is getting added to both the image element. What is wrong in my code? Please help to solve the issue

Comment: First I would be doing `$('.image',images).addClass("invalidImage")`. Second the if statement will most likely always be true.

Comment: Is there any alternative condition to be implemented to check whether which image tag is invalid and add class only to that specific tag alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
if (!src || fileExtension != 'jpg' && fileExtension != 'png' && fileExtension != 'svg' && fileExtension != 'jpeg' && fileExtension != 'gif') {
  $('.image', images).addClass("invalidImage")
}
```

Now it will show the image, if the extension is empty, or if it's not `jpg,png,svg,jpeg,gif`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const images = document.querySelectorAll('.header');
  images.forEach(findImageExtension);

  function findImageExtension(images) {
    var src = images.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src;
    var fileExtension = src.split('.').pop();
    console.log(fileExtension)
    if (!src || fileExtension != 'jpg' && fileExtension != 'png' && fileExtension != 'svg' && fileExtension != 'jpeg' && fileExtension != 'gif') {
      $('.image', images).addClass("invalidImage")
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.image.invalidImage {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <img loading="lazy" data-object-fit="" class="image" src="/sites/default/files/2021-02/DOVE%C2%AE%20PROMISES%C2%AE%20Silky%20Smooth%20Dark%20Chocolate.jpg" alt="DOVE® PROMISES® Silky Smooth Dark Chocolate">

  <h2 class="heading">
    DOVE® PROMISES® Silky Smooth Dark Chocolate
  </h2>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <img loading="lazy" data-object-fit="" class="image" src="/sites/default/files/2021-02/DOVE%C2%AE%20PROMISES%C2%AE%20Silky%20Smooth%20Dark%20Chocolate.bit" alt="DOVE® PROMISES® Silky Smooth Dark Chocolate">

  <h2 class="heading">
    DOVE® PROMISES® Silky Smooth Dark Chocolate
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Carsten. It worked. This is what I expected